# Getting MSI GT70 GT60 ONC LEDs on SteelSeries keyboard working?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, msi

I have an MSI GT70 ONC laptop. The laptop comes with steelseries keyboard that has LEDs in the keys. On windows 7 I can use change the LEDs to light up any colour.

I would like to know how to find out if there is a driver for my keyboard?
If you need more information just tell me the terminal commands.

Answer (score 5):

Was looking for this myself and stumbled upon this [link](http://forum.techinferno.com/msi/5269-msi-led-controller-linux-windows-mac-%7C-msi-klm-alternative.html). Before following those instructions though, make sure you have run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Depending on your Node.js installation, use either:

```
sudo nodejs server.js
```

Or if you installed Node.js from source:

```
sudo node server.js
```

This works on my MSI GT60-2OC. It is a little cumbersome to configure, but not too bad once you get it set up. After getting it running, you can create different files for different lighting options. All of the options are described [here](https://github.com/wearefractal/msi-keyboard).

EDIT: Discovered something new. I believe the quickbar is controlled by the UEFI bios. Originally I wasn't using UEFI in 13.04 and the bar didn't work at all. Now I am using UEFI in 14.04 and I can use some of the buttons including the keyboard backlight button. Using the button cycles between on/game mode/off for me. Using this nodejs program will save the setting you choose and the button will work for that profile until you change it again with nodejs.

Comment: I am one of the creators of msi-keyboard. The final command IS correct Depending on how you installed Node.js. If you use the .deb file you will have a `nodejs` CLI. If you installed it from source (Like me), or change your symlinks, you will have a `node` CLI.

Comment: @SteveLacy Thanks for that clarification and the edit.

Comment: Just released a GUI app for the keyboard: https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard-gui

Answer (score 3):

You can try this program

https://github.com/blackwolf-70/stseries-light

It is using libhidapi library and Qt4.8

The following are the packages required for this script to work.

```
libusb-dev
libusb-1.0.0-dev
libhidapi-hidraw0
libhidapi-libusb0
libhidapi-dev
```

I have tested this in **GE72-6QD Apache Pro** with Ubuntu 15.10 and found to be perfectly working.

Comment: do you have compiling instructions for it?

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can install a command line following the steps indicated here :
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/msi-keyboard_1.1-2_amd64.deb.html

and the codes used for colors regions and intensity in this command can be seen here :
https://github.com/bparker06/msi-keyboard/

Tested on MSI GE72-6QF-072XFR