# Insalling Ubuntu 15.10 on MSi GS70 2QE

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uefi

I have bought a new Laptop and I use Ubuntu for everything. I am planning to remove everything and install it(ubuntu) instead. As for Windows, I have some backup ISO thought in case. Can someone suggest me a list of things I shouldn't miss while installing?

- Booting on UEFI or Legacy Mode
- Graphics driver
- Wireless/Ethernet Driver

> **System Configuration:**
>
> 16GB RAM
>
> 128SSD + 1TB HDD
>
> i7
>
> Killer DoubleShot Pro
>
> GeForce GTX 970M 3GB

Also can you suggest the partition so I can use SSD and HDD in a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I installed it anyway now.

Tried Legacy mode on BIOS and couldn't boot USB drive and reverted back to UEFI it worked

OS trying to install: `Ubuntu Gnome 15.10`

Most of the driver looks OK on `Try Ubuntu without installation`

Missing things:

1. WiFi driver
2. Bluetooth driver

Good thing I had ethernet cable, I then started the installation process and it showed "Install "Ubuntu Gnome alongside Windows Boot Manager"(not tested)

I started with Clean installation:

> ### /dev/sda (128 SSD)
>
> > as 35GB /
> >
> > as 90GB /home
> >
> > as  300MB EFI Boot (Says Minimum 35MB if you donot keep this, may be
> >     sometime later need to install few more things so I kept this)
>
> ### /dev/sdb (1TB HDD)
>
> > as 18 GB already seem to be taken as ntfs so I didn't touched it and left it as it is.(Probably MSI backup drive)
> >
> > as 32GB swap
> >
> > Remaining volume as /home/username/FOLDER (So I can access it easily later)

Message box with (Force UEFI Installation?) popups saying there is another OS with this new efi mode, everything will be erased and nothing can be done with the old OS. Which is what I wanted. ( Stuck for some time, so I just restarted the installation and it was no problem at all later )

- MousePad stopped working after installation but after and Update/upgrade and a restart everything started working even WiFi too.
  `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`. In case if you cannot find still, you can try with the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/691563/456601)
- Keyboard BackLight looks cool now after minor [tweak](https://askubuntu.com/a/502250/456601).
- Nvidia driver works perfectly fine with the default `Additional Drivers` setting
- The only thing missing is bluetooth with is not much of concern for me, thought `lsusb` shows it is there.
- `uname -a` results `Linux username 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

My Conclusion on MSi GS70 2QE and related model:

- Prefect for gaming
- Everything works on UEFI Boot mode
- Probably should work on dual boot with Windows
- Installing Ethernet during one time basic setup would be recommended as it finds and updates required for current system
- Missing bluetooth driver which might be available soon
- Switching graphics needs Logout(restart session) or even Restart sometimes

If you have any question regarding installation on MSi Gaming series feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu in dual boot you should:

- set the boot to the UEFI mode
- activate the boot menu option in the bios in case it isn't
- boot on Windows
- go to the advanced boot settings
- choose to boot using a flash drive(in case you use that)
- boot on your flash drive and install your Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want to try complete cleanup as my SSD is taken by Windows.

Comment: Ok...Try the 2nd answer up there and keep is informed

Comment: Thanks I have already installed Ubuntu on it now. To be precise, I wasn't asking for the steps to install rather the best possible thing I would do with my SSD/HDD and other drivers

Comment: Oh okay. If you haven't expected answers you could ask specific questions