# change color on msi keyboard steelseries

Tags: keyboard, msi

I installed ubuntu 15.10 on my msi GS70. I want to change the keyboard color, i can light up/down with fn+ and fn- but I can't change the color. I tried to follow:
[Getting MSI GT70 GT60 ONC LEDs on SteelSeries keyboard working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284580/getting-msi-gt70-gt60-onc-leds-on-steelseries-keyboard-working)

When I used "sudo node server.js" I  have:

```
 /home/meirdrarel/msi-klm/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/setColor.js:24
    keyboard.sendFeatureReport(activate);
             ^

Error: could not send feature report to device

    at Error (native)
    at module.exports (/home/meirdrarel/msi-klm/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/setColor.js:24:11)
    at HID.board.color (/home/meirdrarel/msi-klm/node_modules/msi-keyboard/lib/findKeyboard.js:12:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/meirdrarel/msi-klm/server.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

node v5.5.0
npm v3.6.0

How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I am the creator of the project.

Please install the latest version of `msi-keyboard`, or install the keyboard LED manager app from here: https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard-gui

The issue you are having is due to a buffer error in `node-hid` fixed in our recent release.