# Backlight keyboard on MSI GT72 latop

Tags: keyboard-backlight

I know people have already asked about installing Steel Series manager on Ubuntu and it is not possible. However, after I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 the back light keyboard on my lap top will now light up! I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the color from stock white now that it is at least lighting up.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is possible. Take a look at this project: https://github.com/stevelacy/msi-keyboard and this askubuntu post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284580/getting-msi-gt70-gt60-onc-leds-on-steelseries-keyboard-working , as well as this post on the MSI forums: https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=265477.0